# I want to setting T4 Template with wildcard in csproj

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, code-generation, t4, csproj

## What I do

I have multiple tt files in my project file.
Therefore, many entries are created for each file as follows.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="Sample.cs">
    <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    <DependentUpon>Sample.tt</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="Sample.tt">
    <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>Sample.cs</LastGenOutput>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

I want to prevent making this entry for every tt file.

## What I have tried

The following statements were made using wildcards.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="**/*.tt.cs">
    <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    <DependentUpon>%(Filename)</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
  <None Update="**/*.tt">
    <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>%(Filename).tt.cs</LastGenOutput>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

The following settings are used in the tt file.

```xml
<#@ output extension="tt.cs" #>
```

## Problem

T4 works, but when I save the tt file, the following entry is added to csproj.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="Sample.tt.cs">
    <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

## Question

How can I prevent entries from being added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see the description of Update from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022#attributes)

> Enables you to modify metadata of an item; typically used to override
> the default metadata of specific items after a group of items is
> intially specified (such as with a wildcard).

Update overrides Compile when save the tt file, so this code will be added to scproj. This doesn't seem to prevent.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="Sample.tt.cs">
    <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```